# How to filter records when filter is a comma separated list of values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has a column in it containing a string of comma separated values (CSV).

e.g. VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3

Being passed in as a filter is another set of CSV.

e.g. VALUE2, VALUE3

So in the example above, the query should return any records where any of the filter values are in the CSV column.

**Example**

```
declare @table table
(
    rownum int,
    csv nvarchar(300)
)

insert into @table values (1,'VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3')
insert into @table values (2,'VALUE1, VALUE2')
insert into @table values (3,'VALUE1, VALUE3')
insert into @table values (4,'VALUE3, VALUE4')
insert into @table values (5,'VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3')
insert into @table values (6,'VALUE3, VALUE4, VALUE2')
insert into @table values (7,'VALUE3')

declare @Filter nvarchar(50)

set @Filter = 'VALUE1,VALUE2'

select * from @table
```

So in the example above, rows 1, 2, 3, 5 and 6 should be returned by a query as they all contain either VALUE1 or VALUE2.

Comment: just to be sure, after your description, it should return all rows, right? Row 4 has VALUE2 which is on the filter, as well as row 7

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I forgot to update the sample code.

Comment: ok. The solution I posted had that in consideration:) It will work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I well understood it, this will solve it:

You create a function to do the split:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_CSVToTable] ( @StringInput VARCHAR(8000), @Delimiter nvarchar(1))
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ( [String] VARCHAR(10) )
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(10)

    WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @String      = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                                ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                                LEN(@StringInput)))
        SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                     ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput), 0),
                                     LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

        INSERT INTO @OutputTable ( [String] )
        VALUES ( @String )
    END

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Then you can do this:

```
declare @table table
(
    rownum int,
    csv nvarchar(300)
)

insert into @table values (1,'VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3')
insert into @table values (2,'VALUE1, VALUE2')
insert into @table values (3,'VALUE1, VALUE3')
insert into @table values (4,'VALUE2, VALUE3')
insert into @table values (5,'VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3')
insert into @table values (6,'VALUE3, VALUE1, VALUE2')
insert into @table values (7,'VALUE2, VALUE1')

declare @Filter nvarchar(50)

set @Filter = 'VALUE3,VALUE4'

select * from @table
SELECT * INTO #FilterTable FROM ufn_CSVToTable(@Filter, ',')
SELECT * FROM #FilterTable
select * from @table where EXISTS(SELECT String FROM #FilterTable WHERE csv like '%' + String + '%')
DROP TABLE #FilterTable
```

I'm considering the description "return any rown containing any of the calues in the filter"

Comment: In SQL server 2016, Compatibility level 130 we can use table-valued function STRING_SPLIT [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(string_split_TSQL)%3Bk(sql13.swb.tsqlresults.f1)%3Bk(sql13.swb.tsqlquery.f1)%3Bk(MiscellaneousFilesProject)%3Bk(DevLang-TSQL)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=sql-server-ver16) instead of above mentioned user defined function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PatIndex to find out the pattern in the field. Like the Following :

```
SELECT * FROM @TABLE WHERE PATINDEX('%'+@FILTER+'%',CSV)>0
```

Comment: Or you could use contains , but this only works if you have a full text index on your table. **select * from @table where CONTAINS(csv, @Filter)**

Comment: Won't work - you may have values in different order, like "VAL1,VAL2" vs "VAL2,VAL1", or contain spaces, like "VAL1,VAL2" vs "VAL1, VAL2" etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (rownum INT, csv NVARCHAR(300))

INSERT INTO @table 
VALUES 
       (1,'VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3')
     , (2,'VALUE1, VALUE2')
     , (3,'VALUE1, VALUE3')
     , (4,'VALUE2, VALUE3')
     , (5,'VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3')
     , (6,'VALUE3, VALUE1, VALUE2')
     , (7,'VALUE2, VALUE1')

DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(50)
SELECT @Filter = 'VALUE1,VALUE2'

;WITH cte AS 
(
     SELECT token = SUBSTRING(
          t.string
        , n.number + 1
        , ABS(CHARINDEX(',', t.string, n.number + 1) - n.number - 1))
     FROM ( SELECT string = ',' + @Filter ) t
     CROSS JOIN [master].dbo.spt_values n
     WHERE n.[type] = 'p'
         AND n.number <= LEN(t.string)
         AND SUBSTRING(t.string, n.number, 1) = ','
)
SELECT DISTINCT rownum, csv
FROM cte
JOIN @table ON PATINDEX('%'+ token +'%', CSV) = 0
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood this question.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work. It returns rows; 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7

Answer (score 0):

What about this now? I didn't have used any User defined functions at all.

```
declare @table table
(
    rownum int,
    csv nvarchar(300)
)

insert into @table values (1,'VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3')
insert into @table values (2,'VALUE1,VALUE2')
insert into @table values (3,'VALUE1,VALUE3')
insert into @table values (4,'VALUE2,VALUE3')
insert into @table values (5,'VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3')
insert into @table values (6,'VALUE3,VALUE1,VALUE2')
insert into @table values (7,'VALUE2,VALUE1')

DECLARE @FILTER VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @IN VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @FILTER='VALUE1,VALUE2'
SET @IN=REPLACE(@FILTER,',','%')
SET @IN='%'+@IN+'%'
SELECT @IN
SELECT * FROM @table WHERE PATINDEX(@IN,RTRIM(LTRIM(CSV))) >0
```

Comment: Thanks but this misses out rows 3 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified @JoseTeixeira code using STRING_SPLIT function.

```
declare @table table
(
    rownum int,
    csv nvarchar(300)
)

insert into @table values (1,'VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3')
insert into @table values (2,'VALUE1, VALUE2')
insert into @table values (3,'VALUE1, VALUE3')
insert into @table values (4,'VALUE2, VALUE3')
insert into @table values (5,'VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3')
insert into @table values (6,'VALUE3, VALUE1, VALUE2')
insert into @table values (7,'VALUE2, VALUE1')

declare @Filter nvarchar(50)

set @Filter = 'VALUE3,VALUE4'

--select * from @table
select * from @table where EXISTS(SELECT [value] FROM string_split(@Filter, ',')
WHERE csv like '%' + [value] + '%') -- Table with filtered records
```